# Can not execute Query on Mouse Event

Tags: java, mysql, swing, nullpointerexception

I have following code,

```
 private void trans_tabMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                       
        try{

         con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/online_store","poornima","mit1234");
          if(con != null){

                String query = "SELECT * FROM bill"; 

                rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                System.out.println("fffgg");
                ResultSetMetaData rsmt = rs.getMetaData();
                int c = rsmt.getColumnCount(); 

                Vector row = new Vector();
                DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)expense_table.getModel();
                while(rs.next())
                { 
                    row = new Vector(c); 
                    for(int i = 1; i <= c; i++)
                    { 
                        row.add(rs.getString(i));

                    }
                 model.addRow( row );
                }

          }

}catch(Exception ex){
     System.out.println(ex);
}
    }
```

in the above code query is not executed. Fired `null pointer exception` at `rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);` line. I tried hours, but I can't figure out where the issue is. Please help.

Comment: where is `stmt` initialized?most probably you have initialized it to null

Comment: At the beginning of the class

Comment: because `stmt` is null, use  `stmt = con.createStatement();`

Comment: Regardless of what you're assuming is happening, the JVM is telling you that stmt is null. Time to find out why.

Comment: @Mani Deep Thanks dude. You make my day!

Comment: @Mani Deep I have another issue in logic. This code return and show all the rows. But duplicate each row(If there is 4 rows it shows 8 rows) and add empty columns to the beginning of the table. Can you figure out the issue as a help?

Comment: @mad_1234 The goal of stackoverflow in not helping you to solve all your problems. The goal is to share with other people the descriptions of common problems and the ways to solve the problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because `stmt` is null.

use this

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM bill"; 
stmt = con.createStatement();
rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
```

instead of this

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM bill"; 
rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
```

refer [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html)

Comment: Yes Its working fine thanks, But it adds few empty rows at the beginning. In DB there is no empty rows at the top. Why this happen?